I need help identifying a WL-CSP IC marked "14901 U25A" and "0120C U12A"
I can't find the chip, please help me. These two ICs may be from the same manufacturer.


(Source: 52audio.com)

please show them in circuit with the surrounding components

This is a poor question. OP did not mention at all that the photos lifted from 52audio.com show the deconstruction of a Garmin Forerunner 245 smartwatch / fitness tracker.

It's probably a Macronix flash memory chip.
Here are my clues:

This question about a chip with very similar markings which is likely made by Macronix (but not confirmed).
Both these websites (1 & 2) show tear-downs of Garmin watches with a similar IC marked M***** U12835, searching U12835 yields the MX25U12835F by Macronix.

I can't confirm this though because Macronix doesn't seem to specify markings and I can't find any pictures of Macronix WLCSP ICs that are confirmed to be real Macronix chips.

Thank you for the information
